# Why i get Error processing element AUDIT for log4j2 in java ee project?

Tags: java, log4j, wildfly, log4j2

In my web module in the resources I have this `log4j2.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration strict="true" name="XMLConfigTest" status="debug" verbose="true"
           packages="hu.pannonris.if3.web.util.appender" monitorInterval="1">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="pattern">%d | %X{session_id} | %X{tranz_id} | %p | [%t] %l | %m%n</Property>
    </Properties>
    <Appenders>
        <File name="FILE" fileName="logfile.log" append="true">
            <PatternLayout pattern="${pattern}"/>
            <Filters>
            <MarkerFilter marker="SQL_QUERY" onMatch="DENY" onMismatch="NEUTRAL"/>
            <MarkerFilter marker="PUT_USER_MARKER" onMatch="DENY" onMismatch="NEUTRAL"/>
            <MarkerFilter marker="GET_USER_MARKER" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="NEUTRAL"/>
            <MarkerFilter marker="SQL_UPDATE_FULL" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="NEUTRAL"/>
            <MarkerFilter marker="SQL_UPDATE" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="NEUTRAL"/>
            <MarkerFilter marker="SQL_QUERY_LIST" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="NEUTRAL"/>
            <MarkerFilter marker="SQL_DELETE" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="NEUTRAL"/>
            <MarkerFilter marker="SQL_CREATE" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="NEUTRAL"/>
            <MarkerFilter marker="SYSTEM_AUDIT" onMatch="DENY" onMismatch="NEUTRAL"/>
            </Filters>
        </File>
        <Console name="STDOUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="${pattern}"/>
            <Filters>
            <MarkerFilter marker="SQL_QUERY" onMatch="DENY" onMismatch="NEUTRAL"/>
            <MarkerFilter marker="PUT_USER_MARKER" onMatch="DENY" onMismatch="NEUTRAL"/>
            <MarkerFilter marker="GET_USER_MARKER" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="NEUTRAL"/>
            <MarkerFilter marker="SQL_UPDATE_FULL" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="NEUTRAL"/>
            <MarkerFilter marker="SQL_UPDATE" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="NEUTRAL"/>
            <MarkerFilter marker="SQL_QUERY_LIST" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="NEUTRAL"/>
            <MarkerFilter marker="SQL_DELETE" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="NEUTRAL"/>
                <MarkerFilter marker="SQL_CREATE" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="NEUTRAL"/>
            </Filters>
        </Console>
        <AUDIT name="AUDIT">
            <Filters>
                <MarkerFilter marker="SYSTEM_AUDIT" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>
            </Filters>
        </AUDIT>
    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <Root level="all">
            <AppenderRef ref="AUDIT"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="FILE"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

In the **appender package** I have the **custom appender**:

```
@Plugin(name = "AUDIT", category = "Core", elementType = "appender", printObject = true)
public class SystemAuditAppender extends AbstractAppender {
private final boolean includeStackTrace;
private final boolean includeExceptionCause;

private SystemAuditAppender(final String name,
                            final Layout<? extends Serializable> layout,
                            final Filter filter,
                            final boolean ignoreExceptions,
                            Boolean includeStackTrace,
                            Boolean includeExceptionCause) {
    super(name, filter, layout, ignoreExceptions);
    this.includeExceptionCause = includeExceptionCause;
    this.includeStackTrace = includeStackTrace;
}

@Override
public void append(LogEvent event) {
    System.err.println("IN APPENDER);
}

@PluginFactory
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public static SystemAuditAppender createAppender(@PluginElement("Filter") Filter filter,
                                                 @PluginElement("Layout") Layout<? extends Serializable> layout,
                                                 @PluginElement(value = "AdditionalFields") final KeyValuePair[] additionalFields,
                                                 @PluginAttribute(value = "name") String name,
                                                 @PluginAttribute(value = "ignoreExceptions", defaultBoolean = true) Boolean ignoreExceptions,
                                                 @PluginAttribute(value = "includeStackTrace", defaultBoolean = true) Boolean includeStackTrace,
                                                 @PluginAttribute(value = "includeExceptionCause") Boolean includeExceptionCause) {
    return new SystemAuditAppender(name, layout, filter, ignoreExceptions,
            includeStackTrace, includeExceptionCause);
}
}
```

If I deploy to `wildfliy 10` I get this error messages:

> Error processing element AUDIT ([Appenders: null]): CLASS_NOT_FOUND
>   ERROR Unable to locate appender "AUDIT" for logger config "root"

And it said: **Took 0,003248 seconds to load 0 plugins from package hu.pannonris.if3.web.util.appender**

So I think, not see the `@plugin` when the `if3web-ear.ear` will deploy. What can be a problem? What I need to do to work? Thanks for the helps!

Comment: How many web modules do you have? Where in your deployment is the "SystemAuditAppender" placed? In the web module or somewhere else in the EAR?

Comment: I have ear-ejb and war and In the web module where is the appender, and i have just one web module(war)

Comment: Does your EJB module also use log4j2? Where in the deployment have you placed the log4j2 jars?

Comment: yes it is also use log4j

Answer (score 0):

The following diagram illustrates what each module in an EAR deployment can "see".

[image: Ear file dependencies]

What this means is that EJB classes and EAR/lib classes cannot see classes inside the WAR.

If your appender is in the WAR then classes in your EJB jar will not be able to see it. Therefore **if you want to use the appender in your EJB jar** then you must move it into a jar that is added to the EAR/lib directory.

Given that the logging in your EJB jar is not completely blowing up I assume that your log4j2 jars are in the EAR/lib directory and you have configured it via your web.xml file.

Configuration of logging in an EAR file can be messy because of these class (and resource) visibility issues.

As you are you using WildFly 10 **your whole deployment can be simplified greatly** by moving to a WAR only deployment that also contains your EJB jar and the contents of the EAR/lib directory:

[image: WAR only deployment]

Comment: Yes i have the log4j2 jars in the lib, but i not setup in web.xml...And other thing is: If I remove log4j dependency from ejb module and add to the war everything is ok... poms: root -> dependency management -> dependency log4j in web i add the log4j and remove from ejb's pom and everythin is ok...why is this? what if i want log in the ejb module? its little bit weird for me...